# Render live session of website and also interact with it

Tags: javascript, node.js

So there are a few tools to record and view live sessions of users on your website using js sdks's like:

1. logrocket,
2. hotjar,
3. https://github.com/rrweb-io/rrweb
4. https://github.com/openreplay/openreplay
5. etc ...

Is there any open source tools or any method of viewing a user's live session with the site but also being able to interact with the user's live session?

If user "John" was learning how to use the site and wanted help and an example on how to do something, he could contact a site admin and the site admin could see John's live session like logrocket does, and with John's permission he could take control and interact with john's session and show how to use the site.

The way I thought something like this would work is serializing the dom and showing the dom to the site admin and when clicking on an element it would send that click event through a websocket to the user's (john's) browser and it would execute the event from the site admin on the user's session.

Comment: What about normal remote desktop tools like TeamViewer and the like?

Comment: because that would be more like streaming video and doing it programmatically would be more integratabtle